# Profiling C++ Destructor Calls

Tags: c++, profile

I am profiling a C++ application compiled on optimization level -O3 with the intel c++ compiler from intel composer xe 2013. The profiler (Instruments on OS X) states that a very large portion of time is being spent calling the destructor for a particular type of object. However, it will not provide me with information regarding what function allocated the object in the first place. Is there any tool that can provide the information on what functions allocate the largest quantity of a certain type of object?

Edit: I have also tried the -profile-functions flag for the intel c++ compiler with no success.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that will work in OS X?

Comment: The strict requirement is that it must work with C++

Comment: If you are using `g++/gcc`, `gprof` will be adequate for your needs, I think. Check out this [tutorial on gprof](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial/).

Comment: Do you control the source code for the object in question?

Comment: Is the constructor defined in a header file or in a separate c++ implementation file (separate compilation unit)?

Comment: It is defined in the header file on account of being a template. Just the constructor is a template, not the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add two more parameters to the constructor, the file and the line number.  Save that information in the object, and print it when the destructor is called.  Optionally you could hide some of the ugliness in a macro for the constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Object
{
    string _file;
    int _line;
  public:
    Object( const char * file, int line ) : _file(file), _line(line) {}
   ~Object() { std::cerr << "dtor for object created in file: " << _file << " line: " << _line << std::endl; }
};

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    Object obj( __FILE__, __LINE__ );
    return 0;
}
```

This is how it runs

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main && ./main
dtor for object created in file: main.cpp line: 16
$
```